# how to generate DTMF tones in j2me

Tags: java-me, dtmf, mmapi

I was wondering if anyone has come across a way to generate DTMF tones in J2ME. I am trying to generate DTMF tones in J2ME, and can't seem to find anything substantial out there.  If anyone has any idea on where I would look for something like this, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: did you look into **[javax.microedition.media.control.ToneControl.setSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/media/control/ToneControl.html#setSequence(byte[]) "API javadocs")** API?

Comment: @gnat. Thanks for your reply. I will check this out. However do you have any sample code or link to site explaining the usages of the same

Comment: ['mmapi' tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mmapi/info) provides a reference to tutorial for that API